# Where was Abraham born?

Tags: time, geography, abraham

Where was Abraham born?

There are a couple of confusing, and perhaps even conflicting verses in the bible about Abraham's original homeland.

The general consensus is that Abraham and his family were originally from the ancient South Mesopotamian city of Ur, though after Abraham embarks and settled in Haran, God says to him:

[Genesis 12:1](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8176/jewish/Chapter-12.htm#showrashi=true) "And the Lord said to Abram, "Go forth from your land and from your birthplace and from your father's house, to the land that I will show you."

This is told to Abraham while he is in Haran, so was Abraham born in Haran? and what does "your father's house" refer to here?

In Genesis 28 Jacob is told to take a wife for himself from one of Laban's daughters in Padan-Aram, and eventually he sets off to Haran.

From this we can deduce that Haran is located in Padan-Aram.

In Genesis 24 Abraham asks his servant to get a daughter for Isaac from his birthplace and father's house, and then the servant sets off to Aram-Naharim where he fetches Rebecca from Bethuel's household. 
Later in Genesis 25:20 Bethuel is described as hailing from Padan-Aram.
Therefore from this we can deduce that either Aram-Naharim and Padan-Aram are synonymous or that one is perhaps an enclave of the other. 
Since Ur and Haran are relatively far from each other, would that mean that Ur was not Abraham's birthplace, or would that mean that Padan-Aram/Aram-Naharim extends to southern Mesopotamia? (Aram-Naharim definitely included Haran, and Abraham was supposedly born in Ur, but his birthplace is evidently in Aram-Naharaim per his servant's journey. So either Ur was never his birthplace or Aram-Naharaim extends till Southern Mesopotamia.)

Comment: Did you read the end of Genesis 11 (ie. the verses just prior to the ones you link to)?

Comment: See first Ramban in Lech Lecho.

Comment: @Double AA Yes, that's how I know Abraham was in Haran. I'm just asking a question, because it is fairly implied that Abraham was born in Haran

Comment: @RandomUser Doesn't that say pretty clearly that Teraḥ moved his family from Ur to Ḥaran? So why do you think it's implied anywhere that Abraham was born in Ḥaran? Clearly he was born in Ur with his brothers. It even says that Abraham's brother Haran was born in Ur.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Sounds like a clear answer to me. I'm not quite sure what more the OP wants...

Comment: @DoubleAA Living in Ur does not necessarily mean he would've been born in Ur. While Abraham is in Haran God says to him to leave his birthplace, indicating or at least heavily implying that Haran was his birthplace

Comment: @RandomUser did u see Ramban breishis 11:28? he touches all your questions!

Comment: @Bach I kind of have a though time understanding medieval rabbinical Hebrew. Translations or a full fledged answer here would be more than welcome