Whose idea was it to leave Ur Kasdim and head to Canaan?
Bereshis 11:31 seemingly reports that it was Avraham's father Terach's idea to leave Ur Kasdim and head to Canaan (although he apparently stalled out at Charan):

וַיִּקַּ֨ח תֶּ֜רַח אֶת⁠־אַבְרָ֣ם בְּנ֗וֹ וְאֶת⁠־ל֤וֹט בֶּן⁠־הָרָן֙ בֶּן⁠־בְּנ֔וֹ וְאֵת֙ שָׂרַ֣י כַּלָּת֔וֹ אֵ֖שֶׁת אַבְרָ֣ם בְּנ֑וֹ וַיֵּצְא֨וּ אִתָּ֜ם מֵא֣וּר כַּשְׂדִּ֗ים לָלֶ֙כֶת֙ אַ֣רְצָה כְּנַ֔עַן וַיָּבֹ֥אוּ עַד⁠־חָרָ֖ן וַיֵּ֥שְׁבוּ שָֽׁם׃
Terach took his son, Avram, and his grandson, Lot, the son of Haran, and his daughter-in-law, Sarai, the wife of Avram. And they set out with them from Ur Kasdim to go to the land of Canaan, and they came to Charan and dwelled there.

Whereas from two pesukim later (12:1) it seems that is was HaShem that commanded Avraham to leave his land, family and father's house—presumably Ur Kasdim—and head to a land that God will show him, which turns out to be Canaan:

וַיֹּ֤אמֶר י״י֙ אֶל⁠־אַבְרָ֔ם לֶךְ⁠־לְךָ֛ מֵאַרְצְךָ֥ וּמִמּֽוֹלַדְתְּךָ֖ וּמִבֵּ֣ית אָבִ֑יךָ אֶל⁠־הָאָ֖רֶץ אֲשֶׁ֥ר אַרְאֶֽךָּ
Hashem said to Avram, "Go forth from your land, and from your family,⁠ and from your father's house,⁠ to the land that I will show you.

How to reconcile?

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83194/where-was-abraham-born.

Hashem is telling him to leave from Charan.

@RabbiKaii See https://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Bereshit/15.7#e0n6 & https://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Nechemyah/9.7#e0n6

See Ibn Ezra on Bereishis 15:7 and 12:1: "G-d commanded Abraham while he was yet in Ur of the Chaldees to leave his country, his place of birth and also his father’s house. The reason G-d told Abraham to leave his father’s house is that the Lord knew that, although he set out for Canaan, Terah would settle in Haran. *Ibn Ezra implies that had Terah gone to Canaan then G-d would not have commanded Abraham to separate himself from his father."

Ramban Bereshis 11:31, 15:7 says that Avraham inspired the move but wanted to honor his father and Chizkuni on these p'sukim repeats Ibn Ezra that Hashem commanded.

@Nahum see https://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Bereshit/12.4#e0n6. Even Seder Hadoros, which has a different chronology from tosafos (Avodah Zarah 9a from וגמירי), holds the commandment was issued in Charan (a different time he was in Charan). See also Ramban: https://mg.alhatorah.org/Dual/Ramban/Bereshit/12.1#m4e2n6
